# ADF Add Custom GUID to Sink

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a Script task where I generate a Custom GUID using SQL: SELECT NewID() AS AzureDataFactoryCustomGuid1

[image]

I'd like to using the output of this in my sink. I'm trying to create an additional column in the Copy Data task using dynamic content but I think my syntax is incorrect.

@activity('Generate Custom Guid for Logging').AzureDataFactoryCustomGuid1

Can someone advise on how I do this please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below expression to get the output of the `script` activity value.

**Script activity output:**

[image]

**Additional column in Copy activity:**

Expression:

```
@activity('Script1').output.resultSets[0].rows[0].AzureDataFactoryCustomGuid1
```

[image]

Alternatively, You can generate the GUID id with function @guid() in the dynamic expression

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I ended up generating a guid() and adding it to my destination and log tables. That way I'll be able to get the activity_run_id from my audit table.